# Inductive Type: Syntax error OCAML

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to create a new inductive type called option:

```
type 'a option = None|Some of 'a
type 'a option tree = Leaf of 'a option | Fork of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
```

I am having a syntax error. 
Why is that?

Comment: It would be super helpful if you reported the syntax error.

Comment: @ Frank Shearar utop says nothing else except "Line ...." Syntax Error

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is

```
type `a option tree = ...
```

instead of

```
type `a tree = ...
```

The rest looks fine.

EDIT 2:

So much about syntax. As to semantics, I am unsure what you are trying to achieve. First let us review what the type does. With the definition fixed as above, an example value of type `int tree` would be

```
Fork (0, Leaf None, Leaf (Some 1))
```

Example values of type `int option tree` would be

```
Fork (Some 0, Leaf None, Leaf (Some None))
Leaf (Some (Some 1))
```

Observe the double `option` in the `Leaf` case. If you instead define your type as

```
type 'a tree2 = Leaf of 'a | Fork of 'a * 'a tree2 * 'a tree2
```

(that is remove the `option` in the right hand side as well) the type `int tree2` would have values such as

```
Fork (0, Leaf 1, Leaf 2)
```

and the type `int option tree2` would have values such as

```
Fork (Some 0, Leaf None, Leaf (Some 1))
```

Which may or may not be closer to your intention.

It looks like you want to constrain the parameterized type `tree` to only be parameterized with `option` types. As glennsl points out in a comment, that can be achieved with the `constraint` mechanism (which I had been unaware of).

Comment: Ok. My point is this is inductive type. I want to create a tree with "option" type!

Comment: If you make the change proposed by @kne that's what you'll have, isn't it? Or you could name your type `option_tree`. You can only use one identifier on the left to name a type. The structure of the type is defined on the right, and can include any types you like.

Comment: You could also do `type 'a tree = Leaf of 'a option | Fork of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree constraint 'a = _ option`. I don't know why you would, but you could.